# Webgrid Column when Null

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, webgrid

I'm trying to dynamically add a link to download file in a `Webgrid`. Inside the relevant column, I'm trying to add an `actionlink` as following:

```
 grid.Column(format: item => @Html.ActionLink(item.FileName != null ? (String)item.FileName : string.Empty,"DownloadFile")
```

But I'm getting run time error saying on the above line of code saying: 
`System.ArgumentException: Value cannot be null or empty.`

Basically when `item.FileName` is `null`, I get this error. I have records in mysql table where there is no file attached to those records and hence `item.FileName` will be null. What do I do to make the WebGrid show nothing in the cell when there is nothing to show?

Comment: if item.FileName is empty just don't create the ActionLink as it will do nothing and an empty link cannot be clicked

Comment: @Gusman How will you accomplish that given above line of code?

Comment: grid.Column(format: item => string.IsNullOrEmpty(item.FileName)? "" : @Html.ActionLink((String)item.FileName,"DownloadFile")

Comment: @Gusman There is a compiler error in your suggested code: `CS0173: Type of conditional expression cannot be determined because there is no implicit conversion between 'string' and 'System.Web.Mvc.MvcHtmlString'`

Comment: replace "" with new MvcHtmlString(""), sorry for the error, I don't use razor ;)

Comment: @Gusman That worked. :) Thanks a lot.